# Encrypting entire disk vs partitions

Tags: performance, encryption, dm-crypt

Which is better ?

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda
```

and then create partitions

or

create partitions on /dev/sda first like sda1, sda2, etc and then encrypt each one of them ?

Will I get less performance from the second approach as different key would be used to decrypt each partition ?

I'll be using ArchLinux and XFS filesystem. With first approach I'm thinking about booting from USB but if there is no performance difference I'm not sure if its even worth it or not ?

Comment: "Better" is a loaded term. Are you after differences in performance only?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, Performance.

Comment: There should be zero performance difference. I'm not sure how you're going to boot if you encrypt the entire disk. The EFI system partition must be plain FAT32. Older GRUB releases need to read Linux kernel and initrd files without encryption (granted it's been solved recently but you haven't specified your distro or its version).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've edited. please check last section

Comment: Again there should be zero performance difference. For the sake of simplicity I'd encrypt the entire disk. Lastly, remember that we're all mortal and if you suddenly perish and don't give anyone your password, your data will be forever lost. I used to encrypt my data and lately I've decrypted it all for this reason. I now encrypt only my laptop partition for work because it contains the data (passwords, private keys, credentials) which could damage if not destroy the company I work for.